# Visual Studio Template

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates, visual-studio-2013

Does anyone know how to make a project template that in Visual Studio that when used to make a new application the original template and all settings won't be changed?

Here is a little more explanation has to what I want to do. I want to make a template that keeps all the project settings for SFML so when I make a new project it will be listed in the templates and I don't have to re-link everything each time I want to make a new SFML application. 
I have tried doing this with the export template settings but it when I do it I run into a few problems like

- I can't open .ccp or .h files other then the ones in the template
- When I edit anything in a new project using the template it changes the original template!

You can probably see my frustration... I am only asking here because I could not find a clear answer or directions to do make a template like I want.

Thanks for any advice or suggestions.

I am using Visual Studio 2013 professional

Comment: Are you open to alternative suggestions other than using the VS project template feature? Create a new project, get all the settings right, add some skeleton code. Then, copy the project folder to some designated location. Now, whenever you need that template, you just copy it using a program you should already be intimately familiar with: your file browser.

Comment: So you did [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xkh1wxd8.aspx)?

Comment: yeah I tried it then found out about this 
http://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=13010.0 
Then I followed it but set up my own temp instead. 
Thanks for the suggestion though.